# Extracting just the actual value from pandas mean() function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print the mean value of a DataFrame column using mean(). However when I print it out I get a load of meta data with it. Is there an easy way to extract just the value, without lots of fancy string formatting acrobatics?

Code:

```
mean = df.groupby('type_airport_large_airport')['frequency_mhz'].mean()

averages_text.insert('1.0', 'The mean for large airport is {}'.format(mean))
```

Output:

```
The mean for large airport is type_airport_large_airport
1    120.240062
Name: frequency_mhz, dtype: float64
```

Thanks!

Comment: `print(mean.iat[0])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@not_speshal has kindly provided the answer

```py
print(mean.iat[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
averages_text.insert('1.0', 'The mean for large airport is {}'.format(mean.values))
```

Comment: @not_speshal has answered the question thanks!

Comment: @frogger it helps to keep track of closed/open questions by checking helpful answers as the answer. If you want to use the answer not_speshal provided, you can make it an answer and mark it complete.